# .htaccess is can not access user's profile

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just write following code for accessing user's profile using .htaccess but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: It doesn't redirect, you get an error, the PHP doesnt get the `username` value, what happens? What is the URL? `a-zA-Z0-9_` can be `\w` and the `/` can be made optional with a `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on your Webserver version you may have to start with an `/`. The last `/` is also optional so we end up with this, assuming `profile.php`  is in your document root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```